# How to resolve the issue of HTTP ERROR 405

Tags: http

I created a Web API project in which the webpage on which I want to display the response from the API is not working. The web page shows "This page isn't working HTTP ERROR 405".

I searched a lot on Google and YouTube to "How to resolve HTTP ERROR 405", but I was unable to find the right content to fix this issue.

How can I solve this issue?

Here is my Web API GitHub repository link: https://github.com/ansu647/CoWIN-sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 405 error indicates when a user requests to access a web page and the web server receives & accept that HTTP method, but unfortunately the server reject that HTTP method so the user can’t access the web page. This causes the error in the user's page. To fix this:

1. Go through your code. It may be it has bugs (or)
2. Shift your application logs and server logs (or)
3. Check the web server configuration file

Comment: Where I have to shift my application logs and server logs?